# How to access name in <script> from <script setup> in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I want to access the "name" variable from <script> in my <script setup> block. I cant seem to figure out how to do it. I have tried importing options from '*.vue' but that prompts me to install module '*.vue'.

```
<script>
export default {
 name: 'some name'
}
</script>
<script setup>
 //use the 'name' variable here
</script>
```

Comment: This may be a case of the XY Problem. _Why_ do you want to access the `name` property? It defines the _display name_ of the component, and otherwise is only used for self-reference in the template. There should be no reason to need it in a component's code.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda agree. But im refactoring a component, and the store makes use of component names, so I was hoping i did not need to refactor the store as well

Comment: You can't do this because `name` is forced to be filename in script setup. If generated name is acceptable, you can use getCurrentInstance().proxy.$options.name , but it's not reliable

Comment: The name is not _forced_, it is _inferred_. You can still set a custom name if you want. Then you should be able to use `getCurrentInstance().proxy.$options.name` and get that name. Try it and tell us what happens :)

Comment: Would this be an okay way to solve it maybe?
`<script>
import NAME_CONSTANT from 'someFile'
export default {
 name: NAME_CONSTANT
}
</script>
<script setup>
 //use NAME_CONSTANT here
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this thing can't be done. You could use `ref` and access its value anywhere in the file.

```
<template>
 <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const name = ref('Jorgen');

</script>
```

If you want to access it's value inside `<script setup>` you have to use `.value`.I have provided the following example in case you want to use it inside a method within `<script setup>`,

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const name = ref('Jorgen');

const showMyName = () => {
   alert(name.value);
}

</script>
```

In brief, if you want to use `name` inside the template don't use `.value`, if you want to use name inside  use `.value`

Answer (score 1):

You can access options exported from `<script>` by creating a circular dependency to the Vue component:

```
<script>
  export default { name: "MyComponent" }
</script>

<script setup>
// HACK: Create a circular dependency to this file to get access to options.
import ThisComponent from "./MyComponent.vue"

console.log(`Setting up ${ThisComponent.name}`);

</script>
```

It also works with TypeScript (lang="ts").